# WP Как получить значения кастомной таблицы в кастомный тип записи?

Tags: wordpress

Есть кастомная таблица `questions`

[image: table1]
[image: table1_1]

Так же есть кастомнй тип записи `qa` который был создан вот так.

```
function create_qa_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Questions and Answers',
        'singular_name' => 'Question and Answer',
        'menu_name' => 'Q&A',
        'add_new' => 'Ask a Question',
        'add_new_item' => 'Ask a New Question',
        'new_item' => 'New Question and Answer',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Question and Answer',
        'view_item' => 'View Question and Answer',
        'all_items' => 'All Questions and Answers',
        'search_items' => 'Search Questions and Answers',
        'not_found' => 'No Questions and Answers found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Questions and Answers found in Trash.'
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __('qa', 'am'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'author',),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => false, // Отключаем перезапись URL
        'pages'=> true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-chat',
    );

    register_post_type('qa', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_qa_post_type', 0);
```

Вопрос, как отображать значения из этой таблицы в админке данного типа записи? Как их подружить ?
Вот нашел про [do_action( "manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column", ... )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_post-post_type_posts_custom_column/)
И пытаюсь вывести значения из таблицы в своей вкладке.

```
// Добавляем колонки в административную таблицу
function add_custom_columns_to_qa_list($columns) {
    $columns['question_text'] = 'Question Text';
    $columns['question_approved'] = 'Approved';
    $columns['question_data'] = 'Question Date';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_qa_posts_columns', 'add_custom_columns_to_qa_list');

// Заполняем колонки значениями
function populate_custom_columns_in_qa_list($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'question_text') {
        // Получаем значение из вашей таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
        $question_text = get_question_text_from_database($post_id);
        echo $question_text;
    } elseif ($column === 'question_approved') {
        // Получаем значение из вашей таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
        $question_approved = get_question_approved_from_database($post_id);
        echo $question_approved;
    } elseif ($column === 'question_data') {
        // Получаем значение из вашей таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
        $question_data = get_question_data_from_database($post_id);
        echo $question_data;
    }
}
add_action('manage_qa_posts_custom_column', 'populate_custom_columns_in_qa_list', 10, 2);

// Получаем значение question_text из таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
function get_question_text_from_database($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'questions';
    $question_text = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT question_text FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d", $post_id));
    return $question_text;
}

// Получаем значение question_approved из таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
function get_question_approved_from_database($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'questions';
    $question_approved = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT question_approved FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d", $post_id));
    return $question_approved;
}

// Получаем значение question_data из таблицы $wpdb->prefix . 'questions'
function get_question_data_from_database($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'questions';
    $question_data = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT question_data FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d", $post_id));
    return $question_data;
}
```

Но пока, что ничего не отображаеться. Только колонки создало.

[image: table3]

Как это исправить? В документации идет про `$post_id` но в моем случаи `$question_id` .
Может я вообще всё не так делаю? Моя задача отображать в админке, если кто-то из пользователей оставил Вопрос о продукте, как бы вы это реализовывали?

Comment: А в чем смысл кастомной таблицы вообще? Приведенный код работает для колонок, но там что-то выведется, когда собственно в таблице будут какие-то записи (в Data Table в админке, имеется ввиду).

Comment: Так у меня ж и вопрос в этот состоит)  Может мне вообще не нужны тут кастомные типы записи ? Я не понимаю, как хранить некий тип записи, который был бы похож на `comments` но для Вопросов/Ответов о продукте?  Вот идея создать отдельно таблицу `questions` отдельно таблицу `answers` а потом как-то єто подружить в админке...

Comment: Почистил предыдущие комменты. Будет проще если сделаете пост тайпом, вместо вашего `approved`, можете использовать дефолтный пост статус `pending`, а `product_id` к которому относится вопрос, можете хранить как мета значение. Конкретно в этом случае, выигрыша с кастомной таблицей как такового не будет.

Comment: До меня всё равно не доходит, как мне создать кастомный тип записи, что б он работал и с `questions` и с `answers`  При том, что ответов может быть несколько к вопросу. https://i.imgur.com/6CjsyW9.png

Comment: А что именно не подходит? Можно сделать иерархический тип записи, где ответ был бы дочерней записью от вопроса, например.

Comment: А можно подробнее, а то совершенно не понимаю как это реализовивать? Вот предположим создал кастомный тип записи `qa` .  Он храниться как и все кастомные типы записи в таблице wp_posts и имеет основную ячейку `post_content` . Как сделать привязки Вопросов с Ответами ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149149/discussion-between-simon-and-blackstar1991).